# How to prove that inverse function of sin exists?

Tags: calculus, inverse

> Consider the function $F$ defined by $F(x) = \sin x$, for $-\dfrac\pi2\le x\le0$ or $\dfrac\pi2\le x<\pi$. Use calculus to prove $\Phi = F^{-1}$ exists. As usual, $x = \Phi(y)$ if and only if $y = F(x)$.

Hello, I am having trouble understanding how to come up with a solution for this problem. What does it mean by "using calculus"?
How does one figure out if the inverse exists besides just interchanging x and y and then solving for y?

Sorry if this is actually very simple, but due to covid my college professor doesn't hold any life meetings and only sends us pdfs of problems to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A function has an inverse if and only if it is one-to-one.  How can you prove the sine function is one-to-one on the given domain?  Hint: take a look at the graph.

Comment: 1. "*How does one figure out if the inverse exists besides just interchanging x and y and then solving for y?*"<---Do note that this merely finds the function's inverse (if it even exists), but does not actually prove its existence. 2. Does [the first line of this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/261581/21813) help?

Comment: as @saulspatz commented, you need to check if the function is one-to-one, and a sufficient condition for having that is having $f'(x)>0$.  This happens for $f(x)=\sin(x)$ in the given interval.